# My css is not showing properly using codeIgniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I'm trying to show css on my table using the codeigniter but it is not working. If I added the css at header part of my html, it works, but the problem is when I created a separate folder for css the design is not working. I do it correctly as I followed the example online.

Here's my code in View:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>No title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=<?php echo base_url(); ?>"css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h4> Super pagination with CodeIgniter</h4>
    <?php echo $this->table->generate($records); ?>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my code in Controller:

```
    <?php

    class Site extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('table');
        $config['base_url']='http://localhost:81/nine/index.php/site/index';
        $config['total_rows']=$this->db->get('data')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page']=1;
        $config['num_links']=20;
        $config['full_tag_open']='<div id="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close']='</div>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['records']=$this->db->get('data', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->load->view('site_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Here's the Autoload:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Here's the Config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:81/nine/';
```

Here's the database

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'datadb';
```

I don't know if the problem is on the version of the codeigniter. I'm using 2.2.0 while online is 1.7.2.

[image]

should be...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stylesheet is incorrectly linked up (watch the double quotes after `href`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">
```